# How to make input text box to show hindi characters as typed on keyboard for a java application

Tags: java, text, input, internationalization

It is a completed java desktop application and now need it to accept entries for data fields, input boxes, etc to be made in native language by non English speaking workers. 
So, essentially need a less invasive approach to actually internationalize the application to be usable in more than one localized regions. Asking my hurdles in step by step manner -

1. what would be the ways to make a text input box show non english characters as they are typed from the keyboard?
2. is there any way to directly use unicode/ hexcode of the entered text strings?

Comment: What have you actually tried? Strings in Java are in Unicode, and JTextField supports Unicode as well.

Comment: tried setting non-english font but it is not entering non-english characters on key-press instead keeps entering english text. encoding for the java environment is set to utf-8 (no success with utf-16 too).

Comment: Could you tell us the OS used, the version of Java and the font you tried?

Comment: Windows 7, jdk 7, aparajita, devanagri, kriti and some other hindi fonts (on netbeans IDE 7.1). Is setting font for the text control the right way to get the required behavior or could be something else also that I might be missing. Had already set the locale for the language though.

Comment: update: first part is done, i.e. now getting non-english font in text controls. It all started working after restarting the netbeans IDE, guess something was not getting picked properly by ide until restart, maybe encoding part! So, as it turns out - solution is just setting the right font for the control and correct encoding format for application/ java environment.